# Interruption Pesukei dezimra? (ה' מלך ה' מלך ה' ימלוך לעולם)

Tags: pesukei-dezimra

Does anyone know what the law is regarding saying

> ה' מלך ה' מלך ה' ימלוך לעולם  ועד

if someone already has started saying Pesukei dezimra?

Is it considered an interruption or an obligation to say when everyone else is saying it aloud (as per custom of some nussachim) and you have already gotten up to at least saying Psalm 30 or have begun Baruch Sheamar?

Comment: Is there any issue of hefsek before Baruch Sheamar?  Obviously if you stop in the middle of a pasuk it doesn't make sense, but beyond that I've never heard of hefsek problems during mizmor shir.

Comment: I mentioned Psalm 30 as well for good measure (because I wasn't sure of another possible stringency involved regarding this case) even though Psalm 30 is technically "preliminary" Pesukei dezimra as I recall (correct me if I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. 
Once one begins Pesukei deZimra, his ability to respond to various parts of davening are already limited. See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 51:2-5 and the commentary you follow's comments there for specific examples.

Hashem Melech is not a Beracha or Davar SheBeKedushah that warrants interrupting for between the Berahot of Baruch SheAmar and Yishtabach. It is only a Minhag that took hold in the past half millennia to say Hashem Melech every day.

Even if one is in middle of Korbanot, where it is permissible to answer anything, he need not answer Hashem Melech, though he should stand, as elaborated by the Beit Yosef Orach Chaim 50, Shaar HaKavanot, Ben Ish Chai (Shanah Rishonah, Parashat Vayigash 1), and Kaf HaChaim 50:8.

All the more so would it seem reasonable to say that one may not say Hashem Melech along with the Tzibbur in middle of Pesukei deZimra.

For greater exploration, see Yalkut Yosef (Hilchot Pesukei DeZimra uKeriat Shema volume) 48:10

**ילקוט יוסף פסוקי דזמרה וקריאת שמע הערות סימן מח סעיף י**

> אם צריך לעמוד עם הצבור בעת שאומרים ה' מלך
>   בכף החיים פלאג'י (סימן יח אות ז) כתב, השומע מהצבור שאומרים ה' מלך וכו'
>   חייב לעמוד, ואם הוא עוסק בפרשת הקרבנות או הודו, קודם ברוך שאמר, חייב
>   גם כן לומר ה' מלך עמהם. ע"כ. ובשו"ת יביע אומר חלק ט' (אורח חיים סימן
>   פב אות ה') העיר על דבריו: אבל בשער הכוונות (דף יז ע"ג) ד"ה שני פסוקים
>   וכו', איתא, שני פסוקים אלו של ה' מלך וכו' והיה ה' למלך וכו' צריך
>   לאומרם מעומד, ואף האומר פסוקים אחרים או סדר הקרבנות ושומע שאומרים ה'
>   מלך צריך לעמוד עם הצבור, ואף שהוא בסדר הקרבנות אין צריך להפסיק לומר
>   עמהם ה' מלך וכו', כי אם לקום עמהם בלבד. עכ"ל. נמצא שאפילו אם עוסק
>   בתפלה קודם ברוך שאמר אין צריך להפסיק לומר עמהם ה' מלך. וכן פסק הגרי"ח
>   בבן איש חי (פר' ויגש אות א). וכן כתב בשלמי צבור (דף סו ע"א). ומה שכתב
>   הפרי חדש לחלק שזהו דוקא כגון האר"י ז"ל שהיה מכוין בתפלתו וכו', אבל אנו
>   שאין מכוונים בתפלתינו טוב לאומרו ביחד עם הצבור. הנה מדברי שער הכוונות
>   הנ"ל משמע שאין חילוק בזה. וגם הפרי חדש לא כתב אלא מהיות "טוב", ולא
>   בלשון "חיוב". (ועיין בשלמי צבור שם). ובכף החיים סופר (סימן נ סק"ח)
>   העתיק לשון שער הכוונות הנ"ל, וכתב הרב בן איש חי (שם אות ב), שגם
>   כשאומרים פסוק ה' מלך בסליחות צריך לעמוד עמהם, מה שאין כן כשאומרים ה'
>   מלך בהקפות של שמחת תורה שא"צ השומע לעמוד, וכ"כ בכה"ח סופר שם. גם
>   בהליכות עולם ח"א (עמוד עד) כתב בזה, בזה"ל: הנה כל זה אינו מן הדין אלא
>   ממדת חסידות, וכמ"ש בשבולי הלקט (הובא בכף החיים סימן נ סק"ח), וז"ל: מה
>   שנהגו לומר ה' מלך בעמידה בשבתות וימים טובים, כתב אחי הרב בנימין הטעם,
>   לפי שנמצא באגדה, שמלאך אחד עומד שחרית באמצע הרקיע, ופותח ואומר ה' מלך
>   וכו', וכל גדודי מעלה עונים אחריו וכו'. וכשם שהמלאכים אומרים אותו
>   בעמידה, כך ראוי לנו לאומרו בעמידה, אבל בחול לא נהגו לאומרו בעמידה, לפי
>   שמתבטלים ממלאכתם ואין להם פנאי, ויש שאין אומרים אותו בחול כלל. ע"כ.
>   ועיין במס' סופרים (פרק יח). ונפקא מינה שאם הוא חולה או זקן אין צריך
>   לטרוח ולעמוד. גם "בברוך שאמר" וב"ויברך דוד" שנהגו לאומרם מעומד, אינו
>   אלא ממדת חסידות. וכמו שכתב הגאון מהר"ש גרמיזאן בשו"ת משפטי צדק (סימן
>   ע), שנשאל במי שנהג לעמוד כשאומר ברוך שאמר ויברך דוד, ורוצה לחזור בו,
>   ולאומרם מיושב, האם צריך התרה, והשיב, שאם נהג כן בטעות, מפני שהיה סבור
>   שהוא חייב מן הדין לעמוד, ואחר כך נודע לו שאינו חייב מן הדין, אלא ממדת
>   חסידות, שכן מנהג החסידים, אין צריך התרה. אבל אם היה יודע שהוא ממנהג
>   חסידות, בהא איכא פלוגתא אי מהני התרה...

Comment: Say a person is in the the middle of reading Psalm 30 or is about to begin Baruch Sheamar after having already finished Psalm 30. Could/Should he still "technically" say Hashem Melech...when most of the congregation is saying it aloud?

Comment: Yes, the reason one is limited between Baruch SheAmar and Yishtabach is that they are two Berachot that bookend Pesukei deZimra, i.e. Berachot HaSemuchot. Just as one cannot interrupt between Birkot Keriat Shema for no reason, so, too he may not interrupt during Pesukei deZimra. However, before Baruch Sheamara, there are no such restrictions. One may choose to answer if he likes, as the Ben Ish Chai (ibid) adds that if one isn't in middle of saying Korbanot at that moment, he should answer instead of just sitting there idly.

Comment: In general, that's exactly when one is supposed to say it.